# Can MSVC be configured to throw a compiler error when it runs into an undeclared function?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm currently using MSVC and Visual Studio. If the compiler runs into an undeclared function, it automatically assumes its form. For example, if I forget to `#include <assert.h>` it will assume the form:

```
int assert()
```

The compiler then proceeds with compilation and outputs a lot of "nonsense" errors. This makes it difficult to trace down the actual issue (i.e. a missing #include).

Is it possible to configure the compiler to throw an error if it runs into an undeclared function?

Note, I'm using MSVC in "C" mode where my source file extensions are ".c" and not ".cpp".

Comment: Yes it does this by default; what have you done to suppress it ? - live - https://godbolt.org/z/7WK1fKsb6

Comment: @RichardCritten Hmmm... nothing that I'm aware of. I haven't tweaked any of the compiler settings.

Comment: @RichardCritten The only thing "different" that I'm doing is declaring these source files as ".c" instead of the typically ".cpp". I'm essentially trying to use Visual Studio to program in C instead of C++.

Comment: Re-tag as `C` as the compiler switches compilation mode (different languages) between C and C++ depending on the file extension.

Comment: Project --> Properties --> C/C++ --> General -->Warning level: Level 3 (/W3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSVC compiler will issue a *warning* message when using an undeclared function (if the warning level for the project/file is set to `/W3` or higher). In your case (using `assert` without `#include <assert.h>`), that message will be:

> warning C4013: 'assert' undefined; assuming extern returning int

However, if you want the compiler to generate an *error* for such occurrences you can either: (a) Set "Treat warnings as errors" to "Yes" (`/WX`) in "Properties → C/C++ → General"; or (b) to convert only *specific* warnings to errors, use the `#pragma warning(error:nnnn)` directive in the relevant source files.

With the following line:

```c
#pragma warning(error:4013)
```

the above warning becomes:

> error C4013: 'assert' undefined; assuming extern returning int

… and the project will fail to build.

You can also accomplish the latter (treating only specific warnings as errors) in "Properties → C/C++ → Advanced" and specifying a semicolon-separated list of the relevant warning numbers, or by adding a `/we"4013"` (or equivalent) command-line switch.